# OS/X Open File Dialog not showing recent files (but the files DO show in the normal Finder!)

Tags: macos, finder

I am trying to attached a screenshot to a mail message (in Chrome).  The Finder dialog shows screenshots up to and including *yesterday* ones, but not today.

I have done an ls -lrta on the ~/Desktop directory. It *does* show the new screenshots (as well as the older ones from yesterday and earlier that the Finder dialog also displays).

Why  would Finder not see the newest files?

```
ls -lrta  ~/Desktop

-rw-r--r--@   1 steve  staff      60947 Mar 22 13:39 Screen Shot 2014-03-22 at 1.39.03 PM.png
-rw-r--r--@   1 steve  staff     115951 Mar 22 14:13 Screen Shot 2014-03-22 at 2.13.17 PM.png
-rw-r--r--@   1 steve  staff      86919 Mar 22 22:21 Screen Shot 2014-03-22 at 10.21.55 PM.png
-rw-r--r--@   1 steve  staff     129273 Mar 22 22:22 Screen Shot 2014-03-22 at 10.22.00 PM.png
-rw-r--r--@   1 steve  staff     579218 Mar 27 10:47 Screen Shot 2014-03-27 at 10.47.48 AM.png
-rw-r--r--@   1 steve  staff     573308 Mar 27 10:49 Screen Shot 2014-03-27 at 10.49.38 AM.png
-rw-r--r--@   1 steve  staff     582194 Mar 27 10:49 Screen Shot 2014-03-27 at 10.49.45 AM.png
-rw-r--r--@   1 steve  staff      20618 Mar 27 11:46 Screen Shot 2014-03-27 at 11.46.03 AM.png
-rw-r--r--@   1 steve  staff      20097 Mar 27 11:46 Screen Shot 2014-03-27 at 11.46.52 AM.png
```

-rw-r--r--@   1 steve  staff     163599 Mar 27 11:50 Screen Shot 2014-03-27 at 11.50.38 AM.png

(BTW I can not add screenshot to help display the problem - precisely because of this problem itself!)

**UPDATE**  The problem is that the screenshots are coming in as "NO DATE". See the screenshot (now I can attach it)

[image]

Comment: The issue also arises on OSX Mojave 10.14.6. But exiting the application does not solve the problem. Neither does a restart.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem is not limited to Chrome. Somehow, the open file dialog gets stuck on the date you launched chrome. Chrome thinks that any files created after that date are in the future and therefore it gets confused and sticks them in the No Date section of the dialog. If you quit Chrome and relaunch it, the problem will be fixed for files up to the date you relaunched chrome. User iBen3.1415 correctly root causes this problem in the following Apple discussions [post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3272875). As of OSX 10.9.3 I know of no better workaround other than quitting and relaunching the App exhibiting this problem.

Comment: Nice investigation

Comment: The above issue can be replicated in Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153
 and OSX 10.9.3.

Comment: Changing the sort order from date modified to date added may provide a sort order which shows the newer files in the expected place rather than "No Date"

Comment: The issue also arises on OSX Mojave 10.14.6. But exiting the application does not solve the problem. Neither does a restart.

Comment: @MotionMountain Right click on the title bar above the file list in the file dialog. you'll get a popup. Check modification and uncheck creation date.